# Is my flash drive broken?

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive, dd

I have a usb flash drive which is not recognized when plugged into two of my PCs. Here is what happens when I plug in the drive:

```
[ 1809.142270] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=1234
[ 1809.142278] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1809.142283] usb 2-3: Product: Mass Storage Device
[ 1809.142287] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Alcor Micro
[ 1809.142793] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1809.143306] scsi9 : usb-storage 2-3:1.0
[ 1810.141362] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB Flash Disk   7.76 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 1810.141924] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 1810.146091] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

And here is the rest:

```
ls -l /dev/sd*
sda   sda1  sda2  sda3  sda4  sda5  sdb  

~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sdb’: No medium found
```

Any suggestion on how to bring this flash drive to life? I have tried with gparted and a few other tools including urescue windows

Comment: You have to use `sudo dd`. Make sure if `sdb` is your usb flash

Comment: i have done all commands as root and i have only one usb drive attached the rest are my hdd partitions

Comment: Is it listed with `sudo fdisk -l` ?

Comment: no ls doesnt list the drive the only place it appears is in dmesg when plugged

Answer (score 0):

Generally when there is an issue, you can see an error on the /var/log/syslog.

Otherwise, try to erase by using the right & simple way fdisk:

`fdisk /dev/sdb`

When you entered, press `p` to print the partitions , `n` to create a new partition, `t` to change the file format of your new partition when it prompt you to tap it. When you finished press `w` to write the config (do nothing before).

Comment: verb@verb-LP:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
fdisk: unable to open /dev/sdb: No medium found

Comment: Seems not good... Maybe an other command should works. Try these  to format it (separated by &&): dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=8M && mkfs.vfat -n label_here /dev/sdb1

Comment: root@verb-LP:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=8M
dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sdb’: No medium found

Comment: I think the drive is broken so thanx everyone for your help

Comment: I check on the web too ... Sometimes  by  retrying at one moment it works ...

Comment: Hi @monitor35, verb, and everyone,
 I also facing this issue, on this is my /var/log/syslog when I plug in and out the USB drive (Flashdisk):
https://paste.opensuse.org/23171071
Is that my flashdisk broken?